# How to configure LINQ request

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables:
'AllowedDates'

```
- DayID int PK
- Day datetime
```

'AllowedTimes'

```
- TimeID int PK
- DayID int FK
- Hour int
- Minute int
```

also I have table 'Users':

```
- ID int PK
- FirstName nvarchar(max)
...
```

and table 'UserDeniedTimes':

```
DayID int FK
UserID int FK
Hour int
Minute int
```

I need to select users, which don't have deny time (record in UserDeniedTimes) for concrete DayID/Hour/Minute

I try to do the following:

```
var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
where i.UserDeniedTimes.All(
    p => (!p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(
        a1 => a1.DayID == aTime.DayID
           && a1.Hour == aTime.Hour
           && a1.Minute == aTime.Minute
    ))
)
select new ...
```

it works correctly, but with one exception. If user has record in UserDeniedTimes for some day, but another time, this user is not selected too. For example, UserDeniedTimes has record:

```
DayID = 10
UserID = 20
Hour = 14
Minute = 30
```

this user will be not selected if aTime has the following values:

```
DayID = 10
Hour = 9
Minute = 30
```

but will be selected if DayID = 11. Why?

[ADDED]
it works correctly when I limit only by day:

```
var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
where i.UserDeniedTimes.All(
    p => (!p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(
        a1 => a1.DayID == aTime.DayID
    ))
)
select new ...
```

but not works when I write:

```
var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
where i.UserDeniedTimes.All(
    p => (!p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(
        a1 => a1.Hour == 14
    ))
)
select new ...
```

why? What is difference between magic DayID and Hour ?

[ADDED #2]

```
                     ((time == null) || i.UserDeniedTimes.All(p => 
                        //p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(a1 => a1.DayID != 33) && 
                        (p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(a2 => a2.Hour != 14)
                        ))) &&
```

does not work

```
                     ((time == null) || i.UserDeniedTimes.All(p => 
                        p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(a1 => a1.DayID != 33) && 
                        //(p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(a2 => a2.Hour != 14)
                        ))) &&
```

works

why?

Comment: There's probably another record with DayID = 11, UserID = 20, Hour = 8,
Minute = 30.

Comment: no record with DayID = 11, UserID = 20, Hour = 8, Minute = 30 at all. Only when DayID is not exists for this user record will be selected

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to rephrase the problem: if I read you well, you don't want users, that have a deny time with at least one specified DayID/Hour/Minute:

```
where !i.UserDeniedTimes.Any(
    p => (p.AllowedDate.AllowedTimes.Any(
        a1 => a1.DayID == aTime.DayID
           && a1.Hour == aTime.Hour
           && a1.Minute == aTime.Minute
    ))
)
```

This should select the users you want. If not, please tell in some more words what exactly you
are trying to achieve.